# WordPress splash page with htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, splash-screen

I have a WordPress site set up in the root. I need to set up a temporary splash page to promote an album with an 'enter' button which will lead to the regular site. I know there is a way to do this by moving files to different directories but I'd rather not do that. Is there a simpler way to do this perhaps with htaccess? Or another simpler method?

Comment: you mean you want to show splash page when someone open www.yourdomain.com ? once they click on enter they can view main site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple.

add `DirectoryIndex splash.php blog.php` in your `htaccess` file.

add `splash.php` file in your root directory. add splash page code in this file.

copy `index.php` file and rename new file with name `blog.php`

Login in wp-admin, Go to `setting -> General Settings`

Change Site address (URL) value, it should be `http://www.yoursite.com/blog.php`

That's it!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is to detect the HTTP_REFERER and add a conditional statement to your index.php.  This way client machines will only see the splash when entering in the root url (not by refreshing or clicking home).

Sample code

```
<?php $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match("/yoursite.com/",$referrer)) {
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require('./wp-blog-header.php');
} else {
    header('Location: http://yoursite.com/splash.html');
}; ?>
```

Make sure you have the wordpress comment block on the top of the page.
No .htaccess tweeks needed.

Comment: How does this work? If I click on a link with the URL yoursite.com I don't get the splash page. This is fine as well as desired. But why does this work?

Comment: It detectes the referring page then matches it against your domain (yoursite.com) with a regular expression.  If it matches it loads your wordpress site.  If it does not it redirects you to the splash page.

Answer (score 0):

I used it like this and it works good, so far. Deleted the other stuff from my index.php (not from the theme but from wordpress itself) and left this here:

```
<?php $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match("/great2gether.com/",$referrer) ) {
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
} else {
    header('Location: http://great2gether.com/splash.html');
}; 
?>


<?php
```

Of course you will have to change the domain against your own URL and need to have a splash.html file in your top wordpress folder.

Hope this helps somebody :)